# Put a filter into a future

Tags: scala, future

I want to execute sql statements when the type isn't fruits. This is meant by (type != "fruits" && !isFruits)

I tried the following code, but it drops an error because an else is missing. I don't need an else.

```
if (type != "fruits" && !isFruits) {
      con.executeFuture(query).flatMap(_ => {
        conn.initQuery(query, isVegetables)
        if (isVegetables) {
          conn.VegetableCon.get.queryFuture(RunArgs)
        } else {
          conn.VegetableQueryCon.get.queryFuture(RunArgs)
        }
      })
    }
```

I did some research and found ".filter", so I tried the following code:

```
con.executeFuture(query).filter(_ => type != ("ddl") && !isFruits).flatMap(_ => {
        conn.initQuery(query, isVegetables)
        if (isVegetables) {
          conn.VegetableCon.get.queryFuture(RunArgs)
        } else {
          conn.VegetableQueryCon.get.queryFuture(RunArgs)
        }
      })
    }
```

It drops me the error : "Future.filter predicate is not satisfied."

Now I don't know how to solve my problem. Do you have any idea about my mistakes?

Comment: You have no mistake, the code is doing what you tell it to do. When the input is not what you want it creates a failed future. Maybe all you needed was al `else Future.unit` originally.

Comment: Looks like you query something from the database, and then just discard the result. Do you not care what the query returns? If not, then why bother to make it in the first place?